# Dash path effect making screen sluggish

Tags: android, performance, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a custom view with concentric circles made up of dots. I have attached a screenshot for reference. Till the time custom view just have concentric circles it works fine but as soon as I apply DashPathEffect it makes the whole screen sluggish which is very well observable when you try to open or close the navigation drawer. I have attached the logs below.
Here is the **link to the video explaining the issue**
https://youtu.be/5Mgz4QhXaQI

**Custom View**

```
public class ConcentricCircularView extends View {
    private static final String TAG = "ConcentricCircularView";
    private Paint paint;
    private Context context;

    public ConcentricCircularView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(Utils.dipToPixels(context,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d1)));
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.context=context;

    }

    int onDrawCounter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Log.e(TAG, "Actual radius"+getWidth());
        int radius= (int) (getWidth()/3);
        int distanceBtwDots= (int) Utils.dipToPixels(context,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d10));
        Log.e(TAG, "Counter: "+onDrawCounter++);
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{1,distanceBtwDots}, 0);
            paint.setPathEffect(dashPath);
//            Log.e(TAG, "Current radius "+radius);
            canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2,radius, paint);
            radius= (int) (radius+Utils.dipToPixels(context,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d15)));
            distanceBtwDots= (int) (distanceBtwDots+Utils.dipToPixels(context,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d1)));

        }


    }
}
```

**Logs from console**

```
[![03-22 12:01:38.734 19919-19919/com.lief.smartwallet D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-22 12:01:38.834 19919-19919/com.lief.smartwallet D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-22 12:01:39.474 19919-19919/com.lief.smartwallet I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 12:01:43.184 19919-19919/com.lief.smartwallet I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e65187c time:662629
03-22 12:01:47.559 19919-19919/com.lief.smartwallet D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-22 12:01:47.679 19919-19919/com.lief.smartwallet D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to keep a `boolean` indicating whether you have to draw something. Currently, you are needlessly drawing exact same thing on each iteration.

As stated by Romain Guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414731/1083957):

> In general, hardware layers should be set on views that are expensive to draw and whose content won't change often.

```
public class ConcentricCircularView extends View {
    ...
    private boolean shouldDraw = true;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (shouldDraw) {
            shouldDraw = false;
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            // draw your view here
        }
    }

    public void setShouldDraw(boolean shouldDraw) {
        this.shouldDraw = shouldDraw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, my friend, that didn't work. I have tried the code above, but it didn't work. If I only comment the `//paint.setPathEffect(dashPaths[i]);` in 1st answer, everything works smoothly. I think the problem lies with Dashed path effect.

Comment: @VarunAjayGupta, have you tried setting hardware layer?

Comment: Nope I haven't used that.

Comment: Method `onDraw` is called when the view is marked as dirty by either `invalidate` or `requestLayout`. So this boolean is redundant. Also, setting the hardware layer is usually done on the whole view either permanently or temporarily to animate it. Circles are rendered using texture masks, which is expensive. See [Tips and Tricks - Don't modify shapes too often](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

Comment: `onDraw` may be called multiple times and you should not make assumptions on the count of them. Maybe the parent requests for layout multiple times, if your custom view is not interested to be redrawn you may disregard that. As stated by Romain Guy (Android framework engineer): `hardware layers should be set on views that are expensive to draw and whose content won't change often`, exactly this case.

Comment: It's obvious, that `DrawerLayout` changes this view's color filter when you open/close the drawer. But it makes sense to set the hardware layer once and not in `onDraw`.

Comment: @dev.bmax, [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9S5EO7CLjo#t=34m08s) how Chet Haase & Romain Guy explain why you have to use hardware layer temporarily.

Comment: This is an example of temporarily setting the layer to animate the view (rotation is cheap in GPU). But drawing a circle is expensive in hardware, this is why it should be done only once.

Comment: @dev.bmax, `So this boolean is redundant` - agreed, it should have it's separate setter. Will edit the answer.

Comment: @dev.bmax, `But drawing a circle is expensive in hardware, this is why it should be done only once` OP is drawing this view once, that's why it doesn't matter for this case. I admit that maybe you have a good point, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: AFAIK if you set the layer in `onDraw` then the view will be reloaded into the GPU as a new texture each time unless the system has further optimizations.

Comment: @dev.bmax, I rewatched that video, which was posted 6 years ago. I think you are right on layers also, it makes no sense to switch to software layer, because if the view would be redrawn it would become hardware layer again. Thanks for the comment. Removing `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is doing unnecessary work in `onDraw`. This method is being called up to 60 times a second. So accessing resources or creating objects in this method hurts the performance. Here is a fixed version:

```
public class ConcentricCircularView extends View {
    private static final int COUNT = 10;
    private Paint paint;
    private DashPathEffect[] dashPaths = new DashPathEffect[COUNT];
    private int halfWidth, halfHeight, radius;
    private int dimen15;

    public ConcentricCircularView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // Get the dimensions.
        int dimen1 = dipToPixels(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d1));
        int dimen10 = dipToPixels(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d10));
        dimen15 = dipToPixels(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d15));
        // Setup the path effects;
        for (int i=0; i<COUNT; i++) {
            dashPaths[i] = new DashPathEffect(
                    new float[]{ 1, dimen10 + dimen1 * i }, 0);
        }
        // Setup the paint.
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(dimen1);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        halfWidth = w / 2;
        halfHeight = h / 2;
        radius = w / 3;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (int i=0; i<COUNT; i++) {
            paint.setPathEffect(dashPaths[i]);
            canvas.drawCircle(halfWidth, halfHeight, radius + dimen15 * i, paint);
        }
    }

    private int dipToPixels(float value) {
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (value * scale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code above, but it didn't work. If I only comment the `//paint.setPathEffect(dashPaths[i]);`  above line, everything works smoothly. I think the problem lies with Dashed path effect.

Comment: Lag is still there whenever I am trying to open or close the navigation drawer. You can take a look at this in order to know the exact behavior.
https://youtu.be/5Mgz4QhXaQI

Comment: Are you using `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` with `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`?

Comment: I am using android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout and using a Relative layout as a Navigation Drawer

Comment: A further optimization would be to draw the background and circles to a bitmap once, then draw this bitmap to the canvas in `onDraw`